# OWASP dependency-check maven vs command line not same results

Tags: java, maven, owasp, maven-dependency-plugin, owasp-dependency-check

On a Maven project, I am running both the OWASP dependency-check-maven plugin as also the OWASP command line tool in order to generate a report with dependencies having vulnerabilities.

What I cannot understand, is how those two tools operate. In detail,
I noticed that the Maven plugin (dependency-check-maven) , reports 45 vulnerable dependencies, while the command line tool 34.

For example, the Maven plugin reports the `undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar` (which is provided by the `undertow-servlet` dependency) as having a critical vulnerability, while with the command line check, this dependency does not appear at all in the list.  I am running the command line tool with the following command:

```
dependency-check --project "myProject" --scan "C:\path\myProject" --disableRetireJS
```

Could it be that the command line tool scans for existing jar files in the projects directory while the Maven plugin goes through the defined dependency in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: Are the version of the plugin and the cmd line tool the same?

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/3729, the author of the plugin says:

"The report from the Maven plugin is likely the most accurate. With the CLI it is only scanning the build artifacts."

So, when you use dependency-check-maven plugin the pom.xml are used, while using the CLI only what is found in the target(s) is checked.